# Important use of bandwidth when important number of kafka consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka use that may be a bit different of what is expected :

- 4 topics (3 partitions per topics)
- around a thousand consumer group for every topics
- very little data to exchange (messages around 1ko and something like 10 records per day on every topic)
- consumers are implemented with spring-kafka

Sadly, I observe an important use of bandwidth (~25Mbit/s continuously) and I suppose it's because consumers need to keep the connection with the cluster (This use of bandwidth even happens when there is no messages).

It would be ok for my consumers to not be as effective when it comes to consume the data Is there a configuration of consumers to reduce this network use even if it means not receiving the records in real time.

Do you have any idea why I could have such an important use of bandwidth and also what configuration of my consumers could reduce it ?

Comment: if you don't want consumers to alive, you can do as scheduler once per day or twice per day ?

Comment: @Deadpool : Thanks for the idea. Sadly, I'm ok with not being in real time but not to the point of doing it as a schedule thing. I would be ok with being 15 or 30 minutes but that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce network use, I changed a few settings of my consumers :

First I increased the heartbeat interval :

- session.timeout.ms
- heartbeat-interval

Then, I increased the fetch max wait :

- request.timeout.ms
- fetch-max-wait

For both possibility there is two properties because they are correlated.

Hope it will help someone who had the same issue I did :)